# Could not convert unordered_map<char,char> to unordered_map<char, string>

Tags: c++, string, dictionary

This piece of code runs successfully and results "Character Found".

```
unordered_map<char,char> mp;
mp['a'] = 'b';
char b='b';
if(mp['a'] && mp['a'] == b) 
    cout<<"Character Found";
```

But the following code gives an error:

```
unordered_map<char,string> mp;
mp['a'] = "b";
string s="b";
if(mp['a']) && (mp['a'] == s))
    cout<<"Character Found";
```

The error is :

```
could not convert 'mp.std::unordered_map<_Key, _Tp, _Hash, _Pred, _Alloc>::operator[]<char, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::hash<char>, std::equal_to<char>, std::allocator<std::pair<const char, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> > > >('a')' from 'std::unordered_map<char, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::mapped_type {aka std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>}' to 'bool'
     if(mp['a']) && (mp['a'] == s)) cout<<"Character Found";
```

Why is it so that the `unordered_map<char,char>` works fine but fails in the case of `unordered_map<char,string>` in c++

Answer (score 1):

The condition `mp['a']` doesn't check if an element exists or not, it fetches the value for that key. And if no value exist then it will create a [value-initialized](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_initialization) value that it inserts into the map, and return that value.

That means `mp['a']` will return a `std::string` object, and you can't use `std::string` as a boolean expression.

That makes the check `mp['a']` kind of useless, in both cases. If you want to see if an element exist in a map, you need to [`find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/find) it, which adds a layer of complexity (or use [`contains`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/contains) if your standard library support that upcoming C++20 feature).

Comment: I got the point that i need to use the find() function in order to search the presence of a key in a map. But if the check mp['a'] is kind of useless and we can't use std::string as a boolean expression, then how come it didn't throw an error in the first case of unordered_map<char,char>.

Comment: @RishabhMurarka Because then `mp['a']` would insert and return a `char` with value `0`, and `char` is really an integer type. And integer `0` can be converted to the `bool` value `false`.